# Firebase Storage child ref getDownloadURL returning "childPath.split is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

The error occurs as a result of the .child(blob), and I've tried:

```
.child()
.child({blob})
.child(blob.name)
```

"blob" is defined in earlier parts of the code, it should still be able to refer to it in the storage.

```
        async function handleSubmitUpload() {
        if (recordedChunks.length) {
            const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
                type: "video/webm",
            });
            await storage().ref(`prodReviews/${blob}`).put(blob);
            console.log( "success storing" + (blob));
            await storage()
                .ref('prodReviews')
                .child(blob)
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then((videoUrl) => {
                    firestore.doc(`products/${productID}`)
                    .set({videoUrl}, { merge: true });
                    console.log("Review for item uploaded successfully")

                        setRecordedChunks([]);
                    })

                }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `blob`? The `child()` method is expecting a string. Are you trying to get a download URL of an object that has been uploaded already?

Comment: Yes blob was uploaded to Storage in the code before it.  It's just now I want the downloadURL so the Video can be stored on Firebase and displayed in the project

Comment: Can you share the code that you used to upload the file? You must use the same path in `child()` to get that object's info. Or you can get the reference from the snapshot itself

Comment: I just edited the post to include the full code. I do not have code for "snapshot" I thought it was not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `child()` method takes the path of the object as parameter and not a blob. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
// Create a storage reference
const reviewRef = storage().ref(`prodReviews/${blob}`);

// Upload the object to that ref
await reviewRef.put(blob);

// Get download URL
const videoUrl = await reviewRef.getDownloadURL();

// Add Firestore document
await firestore.doc(`products/${productID}`).set({videoUrl}, { merge: true });
```

Comment: Thank you from a start up in the west coast of the US. Nice you got into YC?

Comment: Change videoRef to reviewRef